# I want to have a policy on my S3 Bucket that will only allow files if they are inside a folder and no files in the root

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, bucket

I have a bucket and I want to restrict people from uploading files at the root. Everything should be inside folders.

I tried creating the following bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "WritePermission",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::nh-test-01/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "*/*"
                }
                
        }
        }
    ]
}
```

But I am getting an error as `Ln 9, Col 4 + 1 more Unsupported Action For Condition Key: The following actions: s3:PutObject are not supported by the condition key s3:prefix. The condition will not be evaluated for these actions. We recommend that you move these actions to a different statement without this condition key`

Thank you

Comment: You can review the allowable condition keys for a given S3 action [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/list_amazons3.html#amazons3-actions-as-permissions). It has no conditions related to the key for `s3:PutObject`. Also, given that your uploads are unauthenticated, how do you propose to prevent people overwriting each others uploaded content? Is there an option to authenticate these users, e.g. with Cognito?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried using StringLike and s3:prefix but I got an error stating cannot be used with PutObject

Comment: That's to be expected because s3:prefix isn't a supported condition key for s3:PutObject.